# Nestjs/swagger: Avoid some Dtos to be shown on list schemas

Tags: swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I'm using some auxiliary Dtos on my rest API, mainly when occurs some error and I use an @ApiResponse, but I don't want to show them as available schemas on the list at the end of the doc.
I have for example:

```
@ApiConflictResponse({ 
  type: ResponsesDto
})
```

However, I would like to display on the schemas just those Dtos corresponding to Create or Update.

Comment: I red on [swagger.io](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/) that setting defaultModelsExpandDepth to -1 are hidden all models, but I want to hide specific Dtos only on the models, not on the model-example.